# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions errorfor dispatching actions

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux here I'm displaying post I'm not understanding whats is going on I read few posts but can't resolve the error

But then I get the error as

**Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**

Following is action reducer and store code please lemme know where I'm going wrong

actionPost.js

```
            import {FETCH_POST} from '../constants/action-types';
            import Axios from 'axios';

            export const fetchPost=(post)=>{
                return{
                    type:FETCH_POST,
                    payload:post
                }
            }


            export const fetchAllPost=()=>{
                return (dispatch)=>{
                    return Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
                    .then(response=>{
                        dispatch(fetchPost(response.data))
                    })
                    .catch(error=>{
                        throw(error)
                    });
                };

            }
```

Post.js

```
                import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import { fetchAllPost } from './Redux/actions/actionPost';
            import {connect} from 'react-redux';
            import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

            const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>{
                return{
                    fetchAllPost:()=>dispatch(fetchAllPost())
                }
            }

            class NewPostC extends Component{
                componentDidMount(){
                    this.props.fetchAllPost(); **// is this correct?**
                }
                render(){
                    return(
                        <div>
                              //display post here


                        </div>
                    )
                }

            }

            const dispPost=connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(NewPostC);
            export default withRouter(dispPost);
```

Reducers.js

```
                    import {  LOG_IN,FETCH_POST } from '../constants/action-types';

                const initialState={
                    userDetails:''

                };

                const rootReducers=(state=initialState,action)=>{
                    switch(action.type){
                    case LOG_IN:
                                console.log("apayload",action.payload)
                                return state;
                    case FETCH_POST:
                                return action.posts;
                    default:
                                return state;
                    }
                };

                export default rootReducers;
```

store.js

```
                    import { createStore } from "redux";

                import  rootReducers  from "../reducers/Loginreducers";


                const store=createStore(rootReducers);
                export default store;
```

Can anyone please help me as I'm stuck since 2 days I wanna understand whats happening and where I'm going.

Please lemme know where I'm going wrong.

**Updated code only the changes I made in those files**

dispPost.js

```
const mapDispatchToProps=()=>{
                return{
                    fetchAllPost   ////////////**A**
                }
            }

            const mapStateToProps=state=>{
                console.log("state",state)
                return{
                    posts:state
                }
            }

            //code here

             const NewPost=connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(NewPostC);
```

reducers

```
            case FETCH_POST:
                                console.log("apayload---",action.posts)
                                return action.posts;
```

store.js
]
When I added the thunk and  applymiddleware  the error vanished

```
                import  rootReducers  from "../reducers/Loginreducers";
                import { fetchAllPost } from "../actions/actionNewPost";
                import { createStore , applyMiddleware } from "redux";
                import thunk from "redux-thunk";

                const store=createStore(rootReducers,applyMiddleware(thunk)); **B**//
                store.dispatch(fetchAllPost());  //**C**
                export default store;
```

Can anyone please explain how **A ,B, C** work Its seems to me  some magic Please lemme know

New Updated

store.js

```
          import  rootReducers  from "../reducers/Loginreducers";                    
                import { createStore , applyMiddleware } from "redux";
                import thunk from "redux-thunk";

                const store=createStore(rootReducers,applyMiddleware(thunk));
                export default store;
```

disppost.js

```
            const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>{
                return{
                   //just fetchAllPost doesnt work if its not dispatch at store or here
                    fetchAllPost:()=>dispatch(fetchAllPost())
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Post.js**

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { fetchAllPost } from './Redux/actions/actionPost';
        import {connect} from 'react-redux';
        import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

        const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>{
            return{
                fetchAllPost // **remove the function declaration, you already did it **
            }
        }

        class NewPostC extends Component{
            componentDidMount(){
                this.props.fetchAllPost();
            }
            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                          //display post here


                    </div>
                )
            }

        }

        const dispPost=connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(NewPostC);
        export default withRouter(dispPost);
```

I would say that would be a good idea to check your store.js, I'm assuming you're using redux thunk. Below some links related to your issue:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/166
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/146

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it helped :) I have updated my code please check. Can you please Lemme know A , B , C .Initially I had not used thunk . I used it then it worked but how is that I did not understand :( whats the logic :/? when I pass thunk to applymiddleware how is it related and works

Comment: A) mapDispatchToProps is passed to the "connect" method, it´s from redux. It´s resposable to inject the "actions" you want to use inside of your component. The same happens with mapStateToProps.

B)it insert middleware when creating the store, it's important to point out that you can insert multiple middlewares. Middleware usually are executed before reach the reducers.

C) sorry, I can´t see why you did this. It's doesnt see right to me.

Comment: firstly, C remove the dispatch action is not called only having "fetchAllPost" in mapDispatchToProps. works when please check new updated code